# How to submit a validated form (that used jquery validate plugin) with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate my form before the inputs will be processed and stored in the database. I used the jquery plugin for validation.

Here is my code for the validation:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

     var container = $('div#error');

      // validate the form when it is submitted
      var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
            errorContainer: container,
            errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
            wrapper: 'li',
            meta: "validate"
      });

      $('#submit').click(function () {

            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
      });

});
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form id="my_form"  method="post" action="#">

      <input class="{validate:{required:true}}" type="text" name="name" />
      <input class="{validate:{required:true}}" type="text" name="age" />

      <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Now, I was wondering if how can I proceed to submit the form after the validation. I am planning to make an AJAX call after it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with what you want to do is that you cannot trust any checks performed only on the client side. You need to authenticate once you hit the server as well.

Comment: Hi @JasCav. I am still trying to learn stuff right now. How would I validate on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `submitHandler` of the `jQuery.validate` options to do something like that.  Please review the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

     var container = $('div#error');

      // validate the form when it is submitted
      var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
            errorContainer: container,
            errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
            wrapper: 'li',
            meta: "validate"
      });

      $('form').submit(function () {
            if($(this).valid()){
                alert("test");
                //do ajax call
            }
            return false;
      });

});
```

this manually checks to see if the form is valid. If it is do what you want with the code. If the form is not valid return false so the form does not post to the server.

Comment: Hey Keith, I will try this suggestion.

Comment: Hi Keith, I tried to put an alert inside the if statement just for my to check if it would be executed but it redirects to the index page due to my <form action="#" />

Comment: What does your html look like. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to post the form to the server or are you trying to just collect information and then do an ajax call to send that information to the server?

Comment: I am trying to get the the data on the form then make an ajax call.

Comment: I've updated my answer. In this case we always want to return false so the submit does not go through. Also remove the # from the action attribute or just remove the action attribute all together

Comment: When I submit the form and there are some required fields that are not filled in I'm having $(this).valid is not a function error.

Comment: What plugin should I include so that the valid() function could be used?

Comment: Here is the microsoft link to the jquery validation source. http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4281/discussion-between-jagadmarx-and-keith-abramo)